# Jmeter - distributed set up - Response body is coming as empty, but response is coming if I hit each server individually

Tags: jmeter, distributed

Issue faced in distributed Jmeter setup

[image]

Hello All,

I connected 4 servers through jmeter - distributed set up, If I run from the master server, I am able to connect all 4 servers and get the response. I am able to see REsponse Code, but Response body is coming as null.

If I run each server individually - I am able to see the response body.

This was working before and stopped working now. Please help me to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, according to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode):

> mode
> sample sending mode - default is `StrippedBatch` since 2.9. This should be set on the client node.
>
> `StrippedBatch`
> **remove responseData from successful samples**, and use Batch sender to send them.

If you want to see response data for any reason you need to add the next line to *user.properties* file on all slave machines:

```
mode=Standard
```

or

```
mode=Batch
```

restart of the slave process will be required to pick the property up.

Be aware that it will cause a lot of network traffic as all the slaves will be transmitting response data to the master machine so make sure you have enough resources to handle this (resources can be monitored using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test))

More information: [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)